# How to pass data with history hook to react functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to implement a redirection after a fetch query is executed.
I want to be able to pass data to the next component (page) with React History.

It would go like this:

```
 const history = useHistory({});
 /* ... */
 history.push({
       pathname: '/page',
       state: { data: data }
 })
```

And then to retrieve the state in the receiver, assuming receiver is a class based component:

```
this.state.data
```

Is it even possible to achieve something like this with functional components? What is the cleanest solution to this problem?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the data you pass to the `history.push` isn't intrinsically bound to class component like that so with a class or a functional component, you'd have to access the location state from somewhere and then assign it to your component's state

if the functional component is being rendered from a route, it should receive `history` as a prop and then you can get that data via simply doing something like `history.location.state`. you can then do whatever you want with it and assign it to state via `useState`

i imagine you can just use that hook `useHistory` to get the location state as well.

something like

```
function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory()

  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(history.location.state)}
  </div>
}

// Rendered via <Route component={MyOtherComponent} />

function MyOtherComponent({ history }) {
  return <div>
    {JSON.stringify(history.location.state)}
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not pass directly state with history but you can easily pass the values which you want to pass with the history like...

> this.props.history.push('export', { value: data.dealer_userid, label: data.user_displayname, nicename: data.user_nicename, invid: data.dealer_invid, date: date });